# supervisor centos troubleshooting after installed twice, with 2 different method

Tags: linux, centos, centos6, supervisord

I have troubleshooting using supervisor on centos 6. first one installed using apt-get, and the second is using yum

1. I cant start supervisor, the error says ".ini file does not include supervisord section"
2. My file /etc/supervisord.conf is empty when im checking using sudo nano

i want to ask how to fixing or reinstall supervisord ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a sample configuration file with:

```
$ echo_supervisord_conf >> /etc/supervisord.conf
```

Then customize according to your needs.

Comment: so actually im just missing my supervisord.conf & my supervisor is fine ?? @valtuarte

Comment: @rizkyredjo yes, having a valid `supervisord.conf` file should do (see [related question](http://serverfault.com/questions/638988/supervisord-ini-file-error-on-centos) in serverfault)

Comment: ok, is that like global setting ? can we create something like "https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues#supervisor-configuration" i want to have like laravel-worker.conf. what should we setting if we want to have many configuration ? like in ubuntu. is that just create that file ? @valtuarte

Comment: @rizkyredjo just add the `[program:laravel-worker]` section as explained in your link, then you can run `supervisorctl reload` to apply changes.

Comment: I have problem now, 2 days ago i can use "echo_supervisord_conf >> /etc/supervisord.conf" command, now i cant use it, it says "-bash: echo_supervisord_conf: command not found" and when im check my /etc/supervisord.conf it is empty. any idea @valtuarte ?

Comment: @rizkyredjo perhaps you're running the command from a different user?